# How to access the current Netty Channel

Tags: micronaut

I would like to use the Netty Channel.attr() to store the HttpRequest for use in library routines.

Anyone know how to find the current channel while in a controller method?

I thought @Threadlocal scope might help, but I can't figure it out (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Netty handlers have `ChannelHandlerContext ctx` parameter in method you have to override. For example, `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`:

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object message) {
    Channel channel = ctx.channel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That steered me in the correct direction.  I found a better solution to my root problem (finding the HTTP request in deep-level GUI code).  I found ServerRequestContext will solve that problem.

Comment: @MikeHouston You can have the request be an argument to your controller method. Avoid using ServerRequestContext unless it is a necessity

Comment: @JamesKleeh.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Is there a reason why using ServerRequestContext might be a problem?  Might it disappear?  I wanted to avoid adding this request argument to every controller.  Some of my view rendering logic needs the Locale and I did not want to add the request as a parameter to dozens of method signatures.  I was looking for something like the RequestHolder from the Spring world...

Comment: @MikeHouston because relying on static state is not a very good idea in a highly concurrent environment. You can create an argument binder to extract the locale from the request and populate a locale argument in your controller. See https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/bind/binders/TypedRequestArgumentBinder.html

Comment: Thanks.  I am still balancing adding the locale to many levels of method calls and using a ThreadLocal-like solution (ServerRequestContext).